# Disable input auto complete on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I know this has been asked a 1000 times, but all the answers say the same yet neither work for me at all.

Here'm my input field:

```
  <input
    className={
      required ? "input-field__input input-field__input--required" : "input-field__input"
    }
    id={placeHolder}
    type={type}
    placeholder={placeHolder}
    autoComplete="new-password"
    value={value || ""}
    onChange={e => handleChange(e.target.value)}
  />
```

I've tried `autoComplete="new-password"`, `autocomplete="new-password"`, `autoComplete="none"` & `autocomplete="none"` but chrome keeps showing me sugestions based on past inputs, no matter which one I've tried. Is there something else happening that might affect it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Comment: Nothing works. Tried to generate a unique input for that autocomplete fields as well by providing it the current timestamp in milliseconds, but still got auto complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add autoComplete="off" in the form tag instead of the input tag. 
Below is the code to follow :-

```
  <form autoComplete="off">
          <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text" />
  </form>
```

{autoComplete} syntax i.e camelCase for React, html follow {autocomplete} in lowercase. JSX also convert it to lower case. You can see the rendered DOM.

Here is the demo :-
https://codepen.io/gahlotbaba/pen/JjdzmmB?editors=0111

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you. Simply setting autoComplete="off" or autoComplete="new-password" in <input> was no longer working and I was losing my mind for a hot sec

Answer (score 0):

you can add a dummy invisible input above your password

```
    <div style={{ height: 0px; overflow: hidden; background: transparent; }}>
        <input type="password"></input>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`autoComplete="new-password"` should work for you.

this will remove the autocomplete

more on this here

https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/issues/1795